# When printing / writing x and y coordinates, numbers > 9 dont match up

Tags: python, input

Trying to get a simple list of x,y coordinates from user input, yet numbers over 9 essentially skip a pair. Ends up looking like this:

1 6

4 9

1

2 7     --- instead of 12 7

```
x = []
y = []

x = input("Write chosen x-coordinate(s) here (with space between each number): ")
y = input("Write chosen y-coordinate(s) here (with space between each number): ")


def datalist():
    global x, y
    for x, y in zip(x, y):
        print(x, y)
datalist()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = input("Write chosen x-coordinate(s) here (with space between each number): ")
y = input("Write chosen y-coordinate(s) here (with space between each number): ")

print(type(x))
print(type(y))
# x and y are strings as input function returns string so you need to split the string to list
x=x.split()
y=y.split()

def datalist():
    global x, y
    for i, j in zip(x, y):
        print(i, j)
datalist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Define x and y as strings, and make them into lists after the user input like so:

```py
x = input("Write chosen x-coordinate(s) here (with space between each number): ")
y = input("Write chosen y-coordinate(s) here (with space between each number): ")


x = x.split()
y = y.split()


def datalist():
    global x, y
    for x, y in zip(x, y):
        print(x, y)
datalist()
```

Basically, what you'll be doing is setting x and y to be strings rather than arrays.

Then, you will use the split() function to make them into lists, with a space as the separator. (split() with no arguments uses a space character as the separator)

Also fixed your input lines, which were missing a closing parenthesis ")".

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like you are trying to build a list from the inputs, hence setting x and y to lists at the start. But the lists are then being overridden by the input statements and you are actually ending up with strings. When iterated over strings yield a single char at a time.

There is a light-touch approach that would achieve what you are going for by converting the strings to lists after the inputs and then splitting each item on a space:

```
x = input("Write chosen x-coordinate(s) here (with space between each number): "
y = input("Write chosen y-coordinate(s) here (with space between each number): "


def datalist():
    global x, y
    
    x = x.split(' ')
    y = y.split(' ')

    for x, y in zip(x, y):
        print(x, y)

datalist()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use split as and when you receive input this way and also x & y would be strings.

```
x = input("Write chosen x-coordinate(s) here (with space between each number):").split()
y = input("Write chosen y-coordinate(s) here (with space between each number):").split()


def datalist():
    global x, y
    for x, y in zip(x, y):
        print(x, y)
datalist()
```